# Cassandra: How to bind PreparedStatement to a map data

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, nosql

Suppose that I have a table in Cassandra which has a map field (`map<int, text>`) named `map1`. And I want to execute this statement:

`SELECT * from TABLE1 WHERE map1 = ?`

After creating an instance of `PreparedStatement`, I will need to call `bind` on it with a valid value for `?` place-holder. How can I do that?

This my incomplete code:

`PreparedStatement stmt = session.prepare("SELECT * from TABLE1 WHERE map1 = ?");
session.execute(stmt.bind(?));`

P.S. Assume I have enabled "ALLOW FILTERING"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindmarker `?` is a *positional placeholder*, and positions are zero-based, so the first bindmarker gets the index `0` and so on. You can bind a value for this placeholder in two ways:

1. Use the `BoundStatement.setMap(int, Map)` method:

   ```
   BoundStatement bs = stmt.bind();
   Map<Integer, String> map1 =...
   bs.setMap(0, map1); // 0 is the zere-based index of your bindmarker
   ```
2. Use the `PreparedStatement.bind(Object...)` method, which is essentially a short-hand for the code above; each argument must correspond to a positional bindmarker in the query:

   ```
   Map<Integer, String> map1 =...
   BoundStatement bs = stmt.bind(map1);
   ```

And finally, because your column is of type `map<int,text>`, the driver naturally maps it in Java to `Map<Integer, String>`. That's why you should use the `setMap()` method in `BoundStatement`.

Comment: Thanks. Just for the record, finally I had to switch to "CONTAINS" and "CONTAINS KEY" to query the map field. As a result, I just needed to bind simple values for key/value of the map and not binding a complete map.